# Swift How to localize an Array for different languages

Tags: swift, localization

I'm trying to localize an array for different languages.

The array that I want localize looks like:

```
var watch = ["This watch is blue", "this watch is red", "this watch is white "]
```

I have already the string localizable and I'm using the method `NSLocalizedString` but I don't know how I can localize the array with all different description.

Thank you for the help

Comment: You could use `NSLocalizedString` for your array instead of an array of vanilla strings.

Answer (score 7):

If you are already setup the localization in your app, you could still use the `NSLocalizedString` in for the array elements instead of direct strings.

Assuming that you have a `Localizable.strings` as:

```
"BlueMessage" = "This watch is blue";
"RedMessage" = "this watch is red";
"WhiteMessage" = "This watch is white ";
```

then you could declare `watch` array as:

```
var watch = [NSLocalizedString("BlueMessage", comment: ""),
             NSLocalizedString("RedMessage", comment: ""),
             NSLocalizedString("WhiteMessage", comment: "")]
```

It would be also an array of strings (`[String]`), containing the localized versions of the strings.